# Permission denied on /etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml; cannot deploy prom/prometheus container

Tags: docker, nfs, ansible

I'm using an NFS mount to provide the `/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml` (default) config file to prom/prometheus docker image all via Ansible. When the container is deployed, I'm getting the following error in the container logs, and the container restarts after a few seconds.

`level=error ts=2020-10-28T16:01:04.432Z caller=main.go:290 msg="Error loading config (--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml)" err="open /etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml: permission denied"`

I can browse the mounted filesystem on my docker host (a Raspberry Pi 4), touch files and read `prometheus.yml` as the user that launches the container.

Below are the relevant tasks from my playbook, and the issue is the same when deploying the container from the CLI *without* the playbook with the remote filesystem mounted to at `/mnt/prometheus`, and passed to the container as a volume at `/etc/prometheus`

`docker run -p 9090:9090 -v /mnt/prometheus:/etc/prometheus prom/prometheus`

**prometheus/tasks/main.yml** (`become: yes` is set in the playbook that calls this role)

```
  - name: "Create mountpoint"
    file: 
        path: "{{ prometheus_mount_path }}"
        state: directory
        mode: 0777
        owner: root
        group: users
        

  - name: "Mount nfs drive for prometheus filesystem"
    mount: 
        path: "{{ prometheus_mount_path }}"
        src: "{{ nfs_server }}:{{ prometheus_nfs_path }}"
        state: mounted
        fstype: nfs
        
  - name: "Create prometheus.yml in mountpoint from template"
    template: 
        src: prometheus.yml.j2
        dest: "{{ prometheus_mount_path }}/prometheus.yml"

        
  - name: "Deploy prometheus container"
    docker_container:
        name: prometheus
        image: prom/prometheus:latest
        restart_policy: always
        state: started
        network_mode: host
        hostname: prometheus
#        exposed_ports: 9090
        published_ports: 9090:9090
        user: 995:1002
        mounts: 
        volumes:
            - "{{ prometheus_mount_path }}:/etc/prometheus"
        comparisons:
            '*': ignore
            env: strict
```

Any idea what would cause or how to resolve the `permission denied` issue from the container?

**Edit:** I tested by providing docker a local directory to share with the container instead of an NFS mount. This was shared successfully with the container, and the container started. Points to NFS issue, but I haven't figured that out yet.

Comment: What are the permissions of `/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml` file inside the docker container?  Does the user that runs the prometheus service have access to read that file?

Comment: @GracefulRestart The container doesn't stay up for long enough that I can check. I have this config (mounting an NFS volume for data that's expected to persist container creation and destruction) running for another service, and it's working w/ identical playbooks, and only changed variables for mount points, image, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my solution and [posted the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64578730/permission-denied-on-etc-prometheus-prometheus-yml-cannot-deploy-prom-promethe/64770154#64770154). Slightly more detail in [my blog post](https://www.jehanalvani.com/2020/11/03/providing-data-persisence.html)